# Excel: Calculate average number of days between a range of dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I'd like a bit of help for a scenario I'll be working on with Excel. Any bit of help will be highly appreciated.

I will have an ever growing range of dates for specific items and I need to make an Excel sheet to determine the average number of days between them per item. Basically, this is a simplified example on how I plan to tabulate the data:

```
Item Code  | Date
A.ITEM     | January 15, 2017
B.ITEM     | January 16, 2017
A.ITEM     | January 22, 2017
C.ITEM     | January 25, 2017
A.ITEM     | January 31, 2017
C.ITEM     | February 2, 2017
B.ITEM     | February 12, 2017
B.ITEM     | February 24, 2017
C.ITEM     | March 7, 2017
```

I will then create another table that will display the average duration between the dates per item. I imagine it will look like this:

```
Item Code  | Average Life Span
A.ITEM     | 9 days
B.ITEM     | 20.5 days
C.ITEM     | 21.5 days
```

What formula would I need to make the second table possible? I've been racking my brain for a while now and, because I'm not very familiar on Date functions in Excel, I still don't know how. Is it even possible?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say "between the dates per item". There is only one date per item. How does Item01 get 9 days?

Comment: To explain using the example table I made above, with ITEM01, we have three dates - 01/15/17, 01/22/17 and 01/31/17. The first two dates are 8 days apart. While the second and last dates are 10 days apart. I then need the average between those durations - in this case, 9 days.

Comment: In other words, I first need to calculate the days between each date per item - date 1-2, 2-3, 3-4, etc. - then average the values.

Comment: ok, sorry, didn't see the item names repeated in the first table

Comment: That's alright. I just realized the table wasn't very clear anyway, I should have used a different name for each item to make them more obvious. I just edited the table for better clarity.

Comment: How are you calculating days apart?  1/22 is 7 days after 1/15.  1/31 is 9 days after 1/22.  1/31 is 16 days after 1/15.  If you have a lot of dates and double count the endpoints, your numbers will be way off.

Comment: I include the first date in the calculation but then I can also work with the normal duration calculation where the first date is not counted.

Comment: I made a mistake with the calculation of item C. I edited the table to reflect the correct calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the average of the differences is just (max-min)/count: (d1-d2) + (d2-d3) + (d3-d4) +... = d1-dn

With that, you can use a formula like
`(MAX(d1:dn)-MIN(d1:dn))/COUNT(d1:dn)`

This would put all the dates in one pot, though, so you need to additionally filter by your codes - instead of simply `MAX(d1:dn)`, use `MAX(IF(a1:an=code,d1:dn,0)` as a matrix formula. Add similar ifs for MIN and COUNT (or use COUNTIF); note that for MIN, the else-value can't be 0, but needs to be something very large.

Comment: just added example of how the final formula would work:  =(MAX(IF($A$2:$A$1001=F2,$B$2:$B$1001,0))-MIN(IF($A$2:$A$1001=F2,$B$2:$B$1001,100000)))/(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$1001,F2)-1)

Comment: Sir Adelaide's answer is closer to what I had in mind so I marked that as an answer. I appreciate your help though and will keep it in mind in case I might need it in the future. Thanks! :)

Comment: Now that I've taken a better look at this answer, I've decided to switch to it as it does not require a layered sort. I couldn't get it to work properly yesterday but I realized today that I should use SHIFT+CTRL+ENTER for matrix formulas. My bad. Haha!

Comment: In my case I modified it to the matrix formula below to match the second example table I gave in my question: {=(MAX(IF(Table1[Item Code]=F2,Table1[Date], 0))-MIN(IF(Table1[Item Code]=F2, Table1[Date], 10000000)))/(COUNTIF(Table1[Item Code],F2)-1)+1}

Answer (score 0):

In this example, Item Code is in Column A, Date is Column B, and then I add new data. Row 1 is headings.

First, you'll need to sort your data each time you add a new row, with a two layered sort:

- first by Item Code
- second by Date

Then, in the column to the right of Date add a Time Between calculation and drag/fill down:

```
=IF(A2=A1,B2-B1,"")
```

Then to average the times.
List the Item codes A, B, C elsewhere - I put them in column F in my test. Next to A, enter and drag/fill down:

```
=AVERAGEIF($A$2:$A$6491,F2,$C$2:$C$6491)
```

I got:

- A: 8
- B: 19.5
- C: 20.5

(for A: 22 Jan - 15 Jan is 7 days, 31 Jan - 22 Jan is 9 days, average is 8 days)

Comment: It's not exactly what I was imagining but this works for me! I just modified it a bit by adding 1 to the duration calculation to match the example I made. I just have to add some conditional formulas and it should work perfectly. Marking this as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I switched to the other answer as it does not require a layered sort. This was useful nevertheless.

Comment: no worries, I thought the other answer was better too