# Formula - Get previous date and sum of unique months based on unique user

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

****Goal*** Estimate the next date Abbie will make the purchase based on average days*.

Screenshot to give a better idea:

[image]

**Questions**

- A.1 & A.2 - how to search for the *most recent* previous purchase date made by Abbie?
- B - how to get unique months and years combination based on Abbie's past purchase date?
- C - how to get for days from previous purchases of Abbie?

Note: I am able to get the count of unique months using formula at [here](https://www.get-digital-help.com/count-unique-distinct-months-in-excel/) but not sure how to make it user-specific

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I can get the value if it's not user-specific (no need to search user & get value). For days between date - DATEDIF(B2, B3, "d"); count unique months - link above; avg days - INT(sum(C2:C10)/C12); estimate next date - (MAX(B2:B10,"<="&TODAY())+C13). Other than that, I also tried to include FILTER into the formula but not success so far @cybernetic.nomad

Comment: `MAXIFS()` should work for A.1 and A.2, `COUNTIFS()` for B (you may need a helper column to separate out months), I don't understand C, what is the result based on your data?

Comment: I think I found the solution. Still validating whether the final number is correct. These 2 pages helped me (a) https://superuser.com/questions/1381471/excel-forecast-future-date-based-on-average-number-of-days-between-a-variable (b) https://superuser.com/questions/1173833/excel-calculate-average-number-of-days-between-a-range-of-dates

Comment: Solution that I got from link (b) 
=(MAX(IF(Col[User]=target user, Col[Date], 0))-MIN(IF(Col[User]=target user, Col[Date], 10000000)))/(COUNTIF(Col[User]=target user)-1)